# JasperReport displaying

Tags: jasper-reports, export-to-word

I have the following structure in my JasperReports, the table consists of:

- set of text fields (as table's headers)
- list (as table's rows)

[image]

However, when I export the report as `*.docx` format, list elements shrink to the left (as displayed in the 2nd picture), but I don't understand why.
[image]

**How can I align the headers and the list rows?**

The full source code at [github:dezmontx](https://gist.github.com/dezmontx/0fb842cf994d83f77c333dfe9dd45023)

Comment: I did tidy up your post a little , hope that helps. I also suggest you extract a some example snippets from your full source code and include it in your post. For more guidance, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example